# How can I export text and image to PDF using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext, rtf, richtext

I am having problems with iTextSharp and exporting to .PDF

I'm using iTextSharp 5.1.2.0. The issue is, however, when I try to export one with an RTF snippet referring to an image, the image does not display.

Also, if I insert any formatting to the document, the rich formatting code appears instead of actually displaying the interpreted text with the formatting. Because the image doesn't export, and the document doesn't keep its formatting, I assume there's something wrong with the code which isn't allowing it to be saved as a rich text document.

My code for exporting the document to PDF is as follows:

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Portable Document Format (.pdf)|*.pdf";
        dlg.FilterIndex = 0;
        iTextSharp.text.Document myDocument = new
        iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4);
        DialogResult dialog = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
            try
            {
                fileName = dlg.FileName;
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                myDocument.Open();
                myDocument.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Rtf));
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error exporting to PDF. Please try again. \n \n" + exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        myDocument.Close();
    }
```

Please see attached images for examples.

Thanks.

[image: Within the application (Formatting)]

[image: Exported to PDF file]

Comment: LOL. The Paragraph class expects you to pass a string as parameter and then displays that string (which is exactly what you're showing in your screen shot). You're assuming that iTextSharp will interpret any RTF syntax you're passing to the Paragraph object. That assumption is wrong. iTextSharp doesn't interpret RTF; you need an RTF interpreter. I'll also edit your question because you're making another wrong assumption about iTextSharp versions.

Comment: I've edited your question as it didn't make sense to say that RTF was supported in version 5.1.2 and not in later version. You're probably confusing the RTF format (files that can be opened in Word) with Rich Text as defined in the PDF specification. Those are two completely different syntaxes (and Rich Text fields are supported in later versions of iText).

Comment: Yeah, thanks and all, but it doesn't really answer my question... I'm new to using iTextSharp, alright?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question because there is no answer as long as you don't have an RTF parser. As explained: iTextSharp won't interpret the RTF. It treats the RTF string the same way as it would treat any other string, whatever syntax is used.

Comment: I removed iText as well as richtextbox. This is NOT a real iText(Sharp) question. Also: you're not talking about a Rich Text Annotation (therefore richtextbox could be confusing). The question sounds like you aren't aware of different syntax descriptions and parsers.

Comment: Alright... So how would I do that then?

Comment: That's a totally different question: "How do I parse RTF documents into text and image bytes?" Surely you don't expect me to answer that question. I consider RTF to be a dead format. I've buried it long ago and I don't know anything about it anymore.